# Angularjs property undefined in controller

Tags: angularjs

Trying to reset password through email. After clicking reset link in email and directed to reset page, console is able to output the "$scope.username" value, however right next line it throws error as "username" not defined. [Error Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wyrYz.png)

Not sure where went wrong. Thanks.

```
.controller('resetCtrl', function(User, $routeParams, $scope, $timeout, $location) {

    app = this;
    app.hide = true; 

    User.resetUser($routeParams.token).then(function(data) {
        if (data.data.success) {
            app.hide = false; 
            app.successMsg = 'Please enter a new password'; 
            $scope.username = data.data.user.username; 
        } else {
            app.errorMsg = data.data.message; 
        }
    });

    app.savePassword = function(regData, valid, confirmed) {
        app.errorMsg = false;
        app.disabled = true; 
        app.loading = true; 
        console.log($scope.username); // test output
        app.regData.username = $scope.username; 
            User.savePassword(app.regData).then(function(data) {
                app.loading = false; 
                if (data.data.success) {
                    app.successMsg = data.data.message + '...Redirecting'; 
                    $timeout(function() {
                        $location.path('/login');
                    }, 2000);
                } else {
                    app.disabled = false; 
                    app.errorMsg = data.data.message; 
                }
            });
        }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Declare  **`$scope.username`**  outside, that will solve your problem, since you are using controller as syntax, it is better to have it as app.username.

```
.controller('resetCtrl', function(User, $routeParams, $scope, $timeout, $location) {

    app = this;
    app.hide = true; 
    app.username = '';
    User.resetUser($routeParams.token).then(function(data) {
        if (data.data.success) {
            app.hide = false; 
            app.successMsg = 'Please enter a new password'; 
            app.username = data.data.user.username; 
        } else {
            app.errorMsg = data.data.message; 
        }
    });

    app.savePassword = function(regData, valid, confirmed) {
        app.errorMsg = false;
        app.disabled = true; 
        app.loading = true; 

        app.regData.username = app.username; 
            User.savePassword(app.regData).then(function(data) {
                app.loading = false; 
                if (data.data.success) {
                    app.successMsg = data.data.message + '...Redirecting'; 
                    $timeout(function() {
                        $location.path('/login');
                    }, 2000);
                } else {
                    app.disabled = false; 
                    app.errorMsg = data.data.message; 
                }
            });
        }
});
```

Comment: Thank you Sajeetharan. However while console is able to output the value of "app.username" one line before the error, the problem still exists.

Comment: what do you mean

Comment: Sorry I didn't realize I could insert the screenshot by editing the question. So I used console.log() function to see if the value has been passed to the variable, it actually does as in screenshot, for both your code and my code. But the next line when I want to use it, it shows undefined.